# Similarities between well ordered sets

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a similarity between well-ordered sets $X$ and $Y$ then $x \leqslant y$ implies $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$.

This is just by the definition.

In later my notes however it says this also implies that $x < y \implies f(x)<f(y)$.

I can’t see where this comes from. Could someone explain this please?

Comment: What is your definition of _similarity_ in this context?

Comment: A bijective function between well-ordered sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $x \leqslant y$ implies $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$.

Comment: Ah, okay; in my experience that’s usually called an _order isomorphism_.

Comment: @Anteater23 if $x<y$, then $f(x)\leq f(y)$ since $f$ is a similarity, and $x\neq y$ since $f$ is a bijection

Comment: Thank you. For some reason that wasn’t obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x < y$. Then $x \leqslant y$ and thus $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$. Suppose now that $f(x) = f(y)$. Since $f$ is bijective, this implies $x = y$, which contradicts the assumption that $x < y$. Thus $f(x) < f(y)$.

Comment: Are these properties equivalent? Does x<y implying f(x)<f(y) automatically imply f(x)$\leqslant$f(y) and therefore $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a similarity?